# Integrate:$\int_{0}^{4a}\int_{\frac{y^2}{4a}}^{y} \frac{x^2 - y^2}{x^2 + y^2} dx \cdot dy$

Tags: calculus, integration

$$\int_{0}^{4a}\int_{\frac{y^2}{4a}}^{y} \frac{x^2 - y^2}{x^2 + y^2} dx \cdot dy$$

The region R:$ \frac{y^2}{4a}\le x \le y , 0 \le y \le 4a$

Graphically,The region is shown below for $a = 1$
[image: Region of the curve]

Let us now change the given cartesian coordinate to polar coordinate

let
$$x = r \cos \theta , y = r \sin\theta$$

then,
$$x^2 + y^2 = r^2$$

now for limits,

$$\because x = \frac{y^2}{4a}$$

putting the values of x and y in terms of r and $\theta$ we get

$$r = 4a \cot\theta \cdot \csc\theta$$

so r ranges form $$0 \le r \le 4a\cot\theta \cdot \csc \theta$$

How to determine the limit for $\theta$ here?

The lower limit for $\theta$ should be $\frac{\pi}{4} [\because y = x]$
but what about upper limit?

Comment: The upper limit is $\pi/2.$ This is because the tangent you $x=y^2/(4a)$ is $(0,0)$ is vertices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are setting up in polar coordinates, the integral is

$ \displaystyle \int_{\pi/4}^{\pi/2}\int_0^{4 a \cot \theta \csc\theta} r \cos (2\theta) \ dr \ d\theta$

The lower limit of $\theta$ comes from line $y = x$. Note that for the entire region, in polar coordinates, we are bound above by the parabola curve and at $\theta = \frac{\pi}{2}$, $r = 0$